# Why using ('function' === typeof x) and not (typeof x === 'function')

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, typeof

In some open source JavaScript projects, I saw people checking if a variable is a function or not with `('function' === typeof x)`. I wonder why people use that instead of `(typeof x === 'function')`.

I feel the second way is more natural. Is there any good reason to use the first way? Performance? Error potential? Or is it just a matter of style?

Comment: Just preference and/or habit.

Comment: If you typo and only put `=`, having the literal on the left is more likely to raise an _Exception_.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=yoda+condition

Comment: yea questioning the use of Yoda Conditions is about as useful as questioning the use of CamelCase vs under_score. Or why Vanilla ice cream is the worst of all.

Answer (score 13):

These are called "Yoda Conditions" (because they sound like Yoda):

[image: yoda]

Some people prefer them, because an `Invalid left-hand side in assignment` error will be thrown if `=` is used by mistake instead of `==` or `===`. In the most usual order (i.e., `if(count = 5)`, a silent assignment will happen, and will screw up the program logic.

Note that `'function' === typeof x` is not a good example; since `typeof x` will evaluate to a string, a misplaced assignment operator will always throw an error in this case, regardless of the order of the operands.

Comment: @Bergi Are you reading my mind? I was going to add the exact same picture!

Comment: I was trying to submit an answer myself, but you were faster than me and mine did not improve anything :-)

Comment: But, I wonder that this is no justification. Your logic is going to break and this approach is more prone to go unnoticed in testing than a syntax error !!

Comment: @hop It's the opposite! Forget the example `typeof x === 'function'`, because it should throw an error with `=` no matter what the order is (due to `typeof` returning a string). But `count = 5` will silently assign to `count` (logic error), while `5 = count` will throw an exception, noticeable in the error console.

Answer (score 7):

They are identical expressions. When you compare with `==` or `===`, it doesn't matter what is on which side of the expression.

```
if(null === myVar)

if('hello' === str)
```

etc. are all valid.

If one of two expressions is quite long, you may want to put it on the right hand side so it's easier for the eye to see what is being compared.

Answer (score 2):

There is no probably no reason but it might historically come from the = and == difference, where it does matter. See the thing with

```
if (a = 5)
```

and

```
if (5 = a)
```

is that the first one doesn't check if **a** is 5, it assigns 5 to **a**. So people came up with the reverse check, which throws compile errors, since you cannot assign to **5**, etc. This way you can fix your code if you forgot one =. So it might be for consistency purposes as well.

Answer (score 0):

They are identical. Some Java programmers tend to write it this way as an usual best practice in Java to write `null != object.getSomething()` instead of `object.getSomeThing() != null`. This is for avoiding the possible *NullPointer*

But, in Javascript this makes no sense. And as you pointed,  `(typeof x === 'function')` is the natural way.