# Javascript if statement is false, but the code is being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have the following global variable declared early on in the script:

```
var ddFinished = 0;
```

This if statement should be false, but for some reason, it's executed as if it's true:

```
$(this).click(function(){
            if (ddFinished = 3){
                $(this).find('.dd_chosen_answer').remove();
                $(this).removeClass("dd_question_dropped");
                $(this).droppable( "enable" );
            }
            else {
                $(this).droppable( "disable" );
            }
});
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax here? The goal is to give myself a variable I can use to toggle whether or not this element will become droppable on click.

In theory (my theory), this should work, but the `if` is executed, event though it shouldn't be according to its circumstance. The variable `ddFinished` isn't declared or changed anywhere else on the script currently.

Comment: `if (ddFinished = 3)` should be `if (ddFinished == 3)`

Comment: It should be if `(ddFinished === 3)`. `==` is never needed and always wrong.

Comment: No, it's not debatable. Give me an example of a use of `==` and I'll tell you why it's wrong.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen `if (something == null)` works for both `null` and `undefined`, and that's a very common situation.

Comment: Anytime you know the type at one side of the comparison, comparing types is not needed. E.g., `typeof somevar == "undefined"`.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen, is not always wrong. In this case, it might be right since the var is initialized to integer and it can be checked using ===.

Comment: @Pointy So why not put `something === null || something === undefined`? It also matches `false`, `NaN` and even `[]`, that's bad.

Comment: @bfavaretto `typeof [var]` gives a string, `===` works here. `==` also works, but is not needed.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I know both work, but my point is that `===` is the one that is not needed in this case. Honestly, I prefer to stop this debate here, as I don't see it ending anytime soon.

Comment: @Sunny if you're doing comparison between a Number and String you're only confusing yourself, you should know the type.

Comment: @bfavaretto my point is, any instance of `==` can be replaced by a combination of `===` statements. This makes code more readable and it more clearly explains what you're comparing. `==` can potentially lead to bugs and you have a good alternative, so it's _always wrong_.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen no, `null` is not `==` to any of those things (`false`, `[]`, `NaN`). The `==` operator is not "always wrong"; it's part of the language.

Comment: `==` is what it is, but you have to to know really well what it does to be able to decide if your comparison does what you want. Splitting it into it's `===` parts make it more explicit and readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
if(ddFinished === 3)
```

Comment: this is the reason old school C programmers used to write if checks like `if (3 == ddFinished)`, because `if (3 = ddFinished)` wouldn't compile.

Comment: that's right. Because "if (ddFinish = 3 )"  assign the value 3 to the variable.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran good point, in JavaScript editors you'd get an error message ...

Comment: @Xander i know, i was just throwing it out how long this has been a common problem.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15094657/825789

Comment: @bfavaretto haha, i've never heard them called 'yoda conditions' before, thx for the link.